# Does Xunit use a source generator for test data?

Tags: c#, .net-core, csproj, xunit.net

My tests are something like this:

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestData))]
public async Task Test(DateTime? startDate)
{
    // Act
    var currentDate = RunCalculation();

    // Assert
    currentDate.Should().BeCloseTo(startDate, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData()
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    return new[]
    {
        new object[]
        {
            now,
        },
        new object[]
        {
            now,
        },
    }
}
```

`currentDate` doesn't depend on `startDate`, but after the test has run, they should be similar.  The problem is not with `currentDate`, but with `startDate`.

The test appears to be called with the `UtcNow` of when the code was *built*, not when the code is *executed*.
If I build the code, then run the test 5 minutes later, the test fails.  If I build and run the test immediately, it succeeds.

**Does Xunit somehow autogenerate the test data at compile time, with fixed values?  Is there something else at play here?**

The csproj files also have `<AccelerateBuildsInVisualStudio>true</AccelerateBuildsInVisualStudio>`, would that effect something?

Versions:

- NET 6
- VS2022 17.9.2
- xunit 2.6.5

Comment: If it uses a source generator, you'll see the generated code under Dependencies > Analyzers > (analyzer name).

Comment: Testing time generally is a finicky thing. Understanding how xUnit works in the background surely is interesting and may help understand what's going on, but I think you should also rethink what you're testing and how you should be testing it. Personally, I would try to use mocks and some time provider that can be configured in order to not depend on the current time.

Comment: I didn't know about the generated code, so that's good to know, but it doesn't appear to be a source generator (at least nothing to do with xunit.analyzers or xunit.analyzers.fixes )

Comment: @Julian I generally do use a fixed time, but that doesn't seem to be the problem really, I'm generating dynamic test data, and it's not ... dynamic !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no source generator being used.

In short without going technical, the `DateTime.Now` is being 'fixed' -- it's encoded into the test case -- at discovery time, subsequent runs will keep using that one, until a new build occurs.

xUnit has a "Theory Data Stability in Visual Studio" topic about that [here](https://xunit.net/faq/theory-data-stability-in-vs), especially focusing on `DateTime.Now`.

You'll notice that the value shown in Visual Studio Test Explorer doesn't change between runs, but only when you rebuild.

[image]

To overcome this, you can include `DisableDiscoveryEnumeration = true` in the `MemberDataAttribute` as shown below. See the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/f22e679603334cb3665751722352b09b0156d517/src/xunit.v3.core/MemberDataAttributeBase.cs#L61).

```
[MemberData(nameof(TestData), DisableDiscoveryEnumeration = true)]
```

---

That same document considers this a bug in Visual Studio and makes the alternative suggestion to use an other test runner:

> The first choice is to use a different runner. To the best of my knowledge, none of the other runners other than Visual Studio Test Explorer exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'd never have found it !

Comment: Thank you for the question; that was a good one!